# Limits with epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

The epsilon delta definition requires there to be a delta for all epsilon but at https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/2-5-the-precise-definition-of-a-limit example 2.41 it says:

Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$

Without loss of generality, assume  $\epsilon \leq 4$ (since $\delta \leq 2 - \sqrt{4 - \epsilon}$), this is allowed because if we can find  $\delta>0$  that “works” for  $\epsilon \leq 4$,  then it will “work” for any  $\epsilon>4$  as well. Keep in mind that, although it is always okay to put an upper bound on $\epsilon$, it is never okay to put a lower bound (other than zero) on $\epsilon$.

I don't understand why a delta for a restricted range of epsilon implies there exist a delta for all epsilon as said above.

Comment: There is a counterpart. If one $\delta$ works for some $\epsilon $ then a smaller $\delta$ also works for the same $\epsilon $. These are self evident from the nature of inequalities given in definition of limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a limit says:

> for every (meaning: for arbitrarily small) positive epsilon there exists delta (implied: small enough), such that...

So we are only interested in narrowing the epsilon range and seeing whether appropriate deltas exist for smaller and smaller epsilons.

If *some* delta 'works' for *some* specified epsilon, we are no longer interested in bigger values of epsilon – the same delta satisfies the condition for them.

Explicitly, if for some positive $\varepsilon_1$ and $\delta_1$ we have that
$$x\in(p-\delta_1,p+\delta_1) \implies f(x)\in (q-\varepsilon_1, q+\varepsilon_1)$$
then for any $\varepsilon_2 > \varepsilon_1$ we also have
$$x\in(p-\delta_1,p+\delta_1) \implies f(x)\in (q-\varepsilon_2, q+\varepsilon_2)$$
because
$$(q-\varepsilon_1, q+\varepsilon_1) \subset (q-\varepsilon_2, q+\varepsilon_2).$$

Comment: why does for all imply small. And what does small mean - it is subjective which contradicts the purpose of a precise definition of a limit

Comment: is it true that $f(x) \notin (q-\epsilon_2,q-\epsilon_1) \cup (q+\epsilon_1,q+\epsilon_2)$ if not why not?

Comment: @user716881 It implies 'small', because if the conjecture is satisfied for any specific value of epsilon, it automatically holds for all greater values – but not for smaller. Hence what we actually _need_ to prove is that the conjecture holds for _every smaller_ value than _any_ chosen one. That is: for all 'arbitrarily small'.

Comment: Thanks, how obout my second comment

Comment: @user716881 Isn't this statement: $f(x)\in (q-\varepsilon_1, q+\varepsilon_1)$ enough to find out the answer?

Comment: Yes, I was just asking for my own knowledge

Comment: @user716881 The set you described is disjoint with the set I quoted. So if the value belongs to latter, it can't belong to the former.

Comment: $(q-\varepsilon_2,q-\varepsilon_1) \cup (q+\varepsilon_1,q+\varepsilon_2) \subset (q-\varepsilon_2, q+\varepsilon_2)$ so if $f(x) \in (q-\varepsilon_2, q+\varepsilon_2)  \implies f(x) \in (q-\varepsilon_2,q-\varepsilon_1) \cup (q+\varepsilon_1,q+\varepsilon_2)$ however there is no $f(x)$ shown to be in $(q-\varepsilon_2,q-\varepsilon_1) \cup (q+\varepsilon_1,q+\varepsilon_2)$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that for each $\varepsilon\in(0,4)$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-2|<\delta\implies|x^2-4|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. You want to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that  $(1)$ holds. If $\varepsilon<4$, you already know that such a $\delta$ exists. If $\varepsilon>4$, take $\delta>0$ such that $|x-2|<\delta\implies|x^2-4|<3$. Then, since $3<\varepsilon$, you know that $(1)$ holds for this $\delta$.